# Como autenticar em uma página web do Firewall via Powershell/Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, batch, powershell, vbscript

Desenvolvi vários scripts em Powershell para automatizar a configuração de máquinas onde trabalho, agilizando e evitando o trabalho pesado de configurar manualmente uma quantidade gigante de estações. Basicamente eles utilizam a desabilitação do UAC, o autologon e o Agendador de Tarefas.

[image: Scripts em powershell]

O maior problema é a utilização do Firewall do Fortinet que pede autenticação via browser, como boa parte da aplicação utiliza arquivos para instalação do servidor via SMB, é preciso fazer essa autenticação. Contudo, ao testar isso pelo Selenium ele até realiza a autenticação, mas após o computador reiniciar e rodar o próximo script, ele pede novamente a autenticação.

[image: login no chrome manualmente]

URL da página: https://authenticator.mpms.mp.br/caplogin/?login&post=http://10.111.147.1:1000/fgtauth&magic=0202e294cb1c7073&usermac=10:e7:c6:c5:c3:61&apmac=00:00:00:00:00:00&apip=10.111.147.1&userip=10.111.147.22&ssid=PGJ-BANCADA&apname=FGT2KE3917900027&bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00&device_type=windows-pc

Segue o código que eu fiz para autenticar no Fortnet, que após o login, faz uma requisição no site globo.com

```
############################################
######## Enable Fortinet Firewall ##########
############################################

$YourURL = "https://authenticator.mpms.mp.br/"

# Adds the path for ChromeDriver.exe to the environmental variable 
$env:PATH += ";C:\Util\PSL\" 

# Adding Selenium's .NET assembly (dll) to access it's classes in this PowerShell session
Add-Type -Path "C:\Util\PSL\WebDriver.dll" 

$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeDriver = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver($ChromeOptions)
$ChromeDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName

# Browse to the specified website
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($YourURL) 

# Methods to find the input textbox for google search and then to type something in it
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("username").SendKeys("username")
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys("password") 
$ChromeDriver.FindElementsByClassName("submit").Submit() 


#### New page #####
$YourURL = "https://www.globo.com/"
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($YourURL) 

Function Stop-ChromeDriver {Get-Process -Name chromedriver -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}

# Close selenium browser session method
$ChromeDriver.Close() 

# End ChromeDriver process method
$ChromeDriver.Quit() 

# Function to make double sure the Chromedriver process is finito (double-tap!)
Stop-ChromeDriver
```

Quando realizamos ela manualmente, as próximas etapas rodam normalmente, o que pela minha conclusão faz com que o driver do Selenium não seja de fato o do Google Chrome, e sim um próprio dele, o que faz com que ele não reconheça a autenticação...

A pergunta que fica é: É possível adicionar essa opção no script para que consigamos autenticar no Fortinet Web e, assim, evitarmos os passos manuais e rodar ainda mais automatizado o nosso trabalho?

Obrigado!

Comment: Tchê, boa noite, se nao atende, não está no escopo desejado, comente, não vejo problemas em apagar a resposta.

Comment: Opa meu amigo. Na verdade atende sim, mas no momento estou viajando no interior do meu estado e não posso testar. Quando voltar poderei implementar. Não pensei na utilização de vbs, pois não conhecia. Pode deixar que utilizarei.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário/resposta, pensei que buscavas uma solução dentro das “plataformas” citas, que n domino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque não usar o **vbs** no **PowerShell** para enviar as **autenticações necessárias?**

```ps1
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $obj = New-Object -com Wscript.Shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('Chrome');
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 300 >$null
$obj.SendKeys('paulogoncalves');
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 150 >$null
$obj.SendKeys("{TAB}")
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 150 >$null
$obj.SendKeys('senhasecreta')
pathping 127.0.0.1 -n -q 1 -p 150 >$null
$obj.SendKeys('{ENTER}');
```

**Obs.:** As duas primeiras  linhas são para trazer  o seu **navegador** para 
 **primeiro plano**!